# INR to USD convert values in opencart

Tags: php, arrays, opencart, json

How do I convert the INR rupees into USD dollars in opencart. I have tried this below code...

```
    $json_from = number_format($item_total, 2, '.', '');
    $url = "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from='.$json_from.'&to=USD";
    $jsons = @file_get_contents($url);
    $json_data = json_decode($jsons, true);
    $to_cur = $json_data['results'][0];


    $data['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT'] = $to_curr;
    $data['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'] = $to_curr;
```

Comment: What is your input ? What output you expect ?

Comment: @Rikesh : see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136378/convert-inr-into-usd-in-opencart-using-json

Answer (score 1):

Your url call for api is incorrect you need to call like,

```
$url = "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=INR&to=USD";
```

From there you will get the conversion rate to convert INR to USD as if now giving `0.0168728` and than multiple with your amount to get expected result.

**Side Note:** You can also pass the third parameter as `&q=4300` to directly get the converted value from the api. *[Example](http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=INR&to=USD&q=4300)*

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/f2WRkf)**.

Comment: is this correct method ?  `$url = "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=INR&to=USD&q=$json_from";`

Comment: Yes it is correct. I have updated my demo please check.